# Identify Site-breaking elements and methods without browser support

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, compatibility

I wrote a web application with HTML, CSS, JavaScript which is accessing several PHP Scripts via AJAX.

Now I am testing my application in the most common used Browsers. Firefox and Chrome were fine, in Internet Explorer 9 and below everything breaks (forms that should be filled stay empty, JS doesn't get executed etc)

Are there any possibilities to identify the elements or methods used in an application that a certain browser can't handle?

I'm not using JQuery, but will definitely next time, since I've read that JQuery takes care of compatibility issues by itself.

Comment: Please elaborate "everything breaks"

Comment: For example, one (fixed) site-breaking element was the usage of "classList" in JavaScript, which is not supported in IE 9 and below. 
What everything breaks means: Forms that should be filled stay empty, JS methods don't get executed etc

Comment: Open in real IE. Use the debugger.

Comment: Some failures will be logged in the IE developer tools. Probably the best place to start.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery which harmonizes methods in to something that usually works in all browsers, you need to do conditional checks e.g. `if('classList' in document.documentElement)`